# insert / update records from one table to another table, no clear join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a list of sku's in one table that I need to assign to product id's in another table the same way that one would in excel, by copying records from a column of sku's and pasting it next to the a column of product id's starting at the first row. I'd like to do this with an update query or other.

```
table1: tmp_pid
fields: pid, sku
```

This is where I have a random number of pid records. The sku field is empty. I'm trying to fill it with date from the next table.

```
table2: tmp_sku
fields: sku, used
```

This is where I keep a very long list of unique sku's and whether they have been used.

I tried this query but it does not work ([Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'tmp_sku.sku' in 'IN/ALL/ANY subquery')

```
UPDATE tmp_pid
    SET tmp_pid.sku = tmp_sku.sku
    WHERE tmp_sku.sku IN (SELECT sku FROM tmp_sku WHERE used = NO )
```

Table1 can have 20 or 1000 pid records, Table2 has 10000 unused sku's. I only need to copy the needed sku's next to the 20-1000 pid records in Table1. I know there is no connecting key between the two, but I am limited to this structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to get this result:

```
select p.*, s.sku
from (select p.*, (@rnp := @rnp + 1) as n
      from tmp_pid p cross join (select @rnp := 0) params
      order by pid
     ) p join
     (select s.*, (@rns := @rns + 1) as n
      from tmp_sku s cross join (select @rns := 0) params
      where used = 'NO'
      order by sku
     ) s
     on p.n = s.n;
```

If so, you can adapt this to an update:

```
update tmp_pid p join
       (select p.*, (@rnp := @rnp + 1) as n
        from tmp_pid p cross join (select @rnp := 0) params
        order by pid
       ) pp
       on p.pid = pp.pid join
       (select s.*, (@rns := @rns + 1) as n
        from tmp_sku s cross join (select @rns := 0) params
        order by sku
       ) s
       on pp.n = s.n
    set p.sku = s.sku;
```

Comment: This is great Gordon. The only thing missing was the 'where used = no' which I added in the second query above the 'order by' in both the select and the update. Thanks much!!!